# Have to press back button in browser twice - why page is doubled in history

Tags: html, redirect

I tested all my websites in Chrome, mobile Safari and IE. BACK button in browser works only if pressed twice. So I think there is something wrong with my websites, example:
**

I've tried to reset .htaccess file and even with file empty I have this problem. I don't use any other redirect and use different hosting...

I don't know where to look, other website (not mine) works fine. Is there any tool to see what exacty happens with redirects and why every page is doubled in history?

Comment: Maybe try removing a few javascripts in a dev environment to see which ones causing it. I havent done this before but that would have been my logical step.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for script to remove parameter from the url and there a lot of suggestions to use:

```
cleanUrl=cleanUrl.replace("#_=_","");
window.history.pushState("", document.title, cleanUrl);
```

Now I changed to **replaceState** and it works fine with redirects!